# Why does api.getRewardAddresses() return an array and does it matter?

Tags: wallet, mesh, cip30

The Cardano dApp-Wallet Web Bridge exposes an `api.getRewardAddresses()` function. This resolves to an array of stake keys, but I have only seen it contain one stake key in practice.

I'm developing a web app and want to store information about users' owned NFTs in a database. Can I use the first element in the stake keys/reward addresses array to identify the user, or should I show a dialogue window that allows the user to choose one? I am not aware of how most sites typically handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the return type to be an array is [CIP-18](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/cip-0018/) (while it is not implemented yet, it is already taken into account in the web wallet bridge specification [CIP-30](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/#apigetrewardaddressespromiseaddress)).

So currently there should not be more than one stake key returned by `api.getRewardAddresses()`.

However: Have a look at the [mangled-addresses](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangled-address) tag to find some more info about possible issues with looking at the stake key to identify ownership of NFTs. In short: Just because a wallet controls an address doesn't mean that it is the owner of the stake key part of the address.

Comment: Thanks for the help!